# Is C++ an open-source project? Which community developes it?

Tags: c++, open-source

I have some questions about C++:

1. Is C++ an open-source project like Linux, Qt, ... or not?
2. Which community maintains C++ and develops new versions?
3. If it is open-source where can one access the source code for C++
   implementations?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

C++ itself is only a description what the language should be,
without a definite implementation.
Anyone can make his own implementations (compiler etc, runtime library, ...)
and call it C++ if it fits to the description.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/

And if a implementation is open source depends on the creator.

Examples of implementation (parts):
GCC/G++, libc/libc++, clang (++ too), Visual studio and MS´ runtime...

Comment: 1. So, C++ is a standard defined by the `open-std.org` and compilers, linkers etc are the implementation? And some implementations are open-source(e.g. GCC, clang) whereas some implementations are not(e.g. msvc by Microsoft). Is my assumption correct? 


2. Regardless of the compiler I am using, we all can use `<iostream>`  , `<string>`.  Where are these implemented? In the compiler? If I want to see how a string reverse function is implemented in GCC or msvc where can I see it?

Comment: @sami1592 1: Yes. 2: The content of these headers is specified by the standard too, meaning every C++ implementation should provide them (but, on every system, there's a lot additional stuff too, not specified by C++ and not the same as in other systems.). The code of this things is compiled to libraries (eg. .dll, .so, etc.). The source of open source ones can be found in Google.

Answer (score 9):

C++ is developed by an [ISO standard committee](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/). There's also a C++ foundation that runs a [web site](http://isocpp.org/) you might want to read.

C++ itself is a language, not a specific implementation, so there's no source code available for the standard/language itself.

Some C++ implementations are open source (e.g., [Gnu](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)).

Answer (score 6):

1. C++ is a code standard defined by the [International Organization of Standardization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization) (ISO). There are many different implementations of the language, but they all tend to conform to [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11). Unlike Linux or Qt, C++ is just a standard, and to use any code written in the language you'll need a compiler. The major compilers (list from Wikipedia) are LLVM Clang, GCC, Microsoft Visual C++, and the Intel C++ Compiler.
2. C++ revisions are dealt with by ISO, and are influenced primarily by the maintainers of the above four implementations.
3. [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) and [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) are both open-source, I'm sure if you poke around you can find other conforming compilers but those are the two most used.

Comment: C++11 implementations [try to] conform to C++11 .. but not everyone has access to such environment/compilers.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is an ISO standard. There are many implementation of compilers (and linkers). GCC is an open source project of many compilers one of which is the C++ compiler, g++:

http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html